# Using VBA external references to refer to a closed workbook UDF

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, range, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create an UDF to get the full path of a range in order to create a hyperlink to that range.

Until this moment, I wrote this code:

```
Function DirCelda(rng As Range) As String

    Application.Volatile
    
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Wb As Workbook

    Set Sh = rng.Parent
    Set Wb = Sh.Parent

    DirCelda = Wb.FullName & "#'" & Sh.Name & "'!" & rng.Address

End Function
```

It works perfectly with cells inside the document, and with ranges in other documents (while they are opened).

i.e.:

```
=DirCelda(F8:G9)
```

returns: **P:\Rodri\LinksExcel.xlsm#'Sheet1'!$F$8:$G$9**

```
=DirCelda('[Caminos.xlsx]Sheet23'!$M$6:$N$22)
```

returns: **P:\Rodri\Caminos.xlsx#'Sheet23'!$M$6:$N$22**

But, when I close the workbook "Caminos.xlsx", Excel (according to explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f)) changes the way that define the parameter including de entire file path.

So, the last example, turns into this:

```
=DirCelda('P:\Rodri\[Caminos.xlsx]Sheet23'!$M$6:$N$22)
```

And it returns: **#VALUE!** error.

I was trying to enable/disable de Application.Volatile method, but when this UDF is used in the HYPERLINK() formula, Excel calculates again the UDF.

I've tried to convert that range into a String to determine the path of the range, but I got the same error every time.

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks in advance.
Regards!

Comment: Not sure this is possible.

Comment: My first idea was to have the function overwrite the `Application.Caller` value with the string address, removing the formula. But my tests to prove that this idea was viable failed because Excel desperately limits UDFs from being able to change other cells, themselves, or anything other than just returning a value.  There are some examples of UDFs that can accomplish this, but I was not able to replicate those UDFs in my version of excel.

Comment: @Toddleson thanks for your reply. I tried to use the `Application.Caller` but it returns me the range where the UDF was called. However, because the purpose is using it inside a formula [i.e.: =HYPERLINK(DirCelda(A1),"Text of the link")], when I get de value of the  `Application.Caller` i get "Text of the link" and not the full path of the range. Thanks again for your help!